# jQuery validation rules is not working in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to PHP and I want to apply jQuery validation in my PHP project. Here is the code of the jQuery, can you please find the error in this section.

```
(function($,W,D)
{
var JQUERY4U = {};

JQUERY4U.UTIL =
{
    setupFormValidation: function()
    {
        //form validation rules
        $("#register-form").validate({
            rules: {
                username: "required",
                joindate: "required",
                location: "required",
                aboutme: "required",
                fileupload: "required",

                emailid: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                agreement: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                username: "Please enter your username",
                joindate: "please enter join date",
                location: "please enter your location",
                aboutme: "please write about urself",
                password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                },
                emailid: "Please enter a valid email address",
                 fileupload: "Please upload a valid image",
                agreement: "Please accept our terms and policy"
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    }
}

//when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
$(D).ready(function($) {
    JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
});

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I don't think `$(D).ready(function` is correct

Comment: @JamesWong - It is when you're passing strange arguments to a IIFE.

Comment: It would help if you described what the problem was and added the html also.

Comment: thanks 4 ur answers @jameswong & dave & adeneo

Comment: @Logan: thanks for wanting to edit questions to improve them. However, there's no need to embolden language names and libraries; PHP and jQuery (and so on) do not need speech emphasis. Fixing the case does make it more readable though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not compulsory, then you can avoid jQuery or javascript validation. As some one can easily over come that by disabling browser javascript. Most importantly you need php validation and to make it more secure use html5 "required" attribute to restrict the user to move forward without entering the value

```
Username: <input type="text" name="username" required />
Password: <input type="password" name="username" required />
Email: <input type="email" name="email" required />
URL: <input type="url" name="url">
```

You can also customize your message by putting a title in it,

```
Username: <input type="text" name="username" required title="Please enter your username" />
```

You can also put conditions on how you want to validate, checkout this [link](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/3/16/A-look-at-HTML5-Form-Validition).

Comment: This is probably more robust than a JavaScript solution, but not more secure - it doesn't make server-side validation any less important.

Comment: ...and this will not work in older browsers, even IE9.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#register-form").validate({
        rules: {
            username:  {
                required: true                    
            },
            joindate:  {
                required: true                    
            },
            location:  {
                required: true                    
            },
            aboutme:  {
                required: true                    
            },
            fileupload: {
                required: true                    
            },
            emailid: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            agreement: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            username: "Please enter your username",
            joindate: "please enter join date",
            location: "please enter your location",
            aboutme: "please write about urself",
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            emailid: "Please enter a valid email address",
             fileupload: "Please upload a valid image",
            agreement: "Please accept our terms and policy"
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
            document.register-form.submit();
        }
    });
 });
```

replace your all jquery code with above code and test , it will work